# Flexbox: responsive column layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns, responsive

I'm having trouble finding out how to use flexbox.

I want a layout with three columns, just like this:

[image: desktop: three columns]

On mobile devices, I automatically want to switch to a one-column-layout.

How can I achieve this?

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-container>div {
    width: 33%;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .flex-container>div {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div>
        <a>Year 1980</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>Year 1981</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>Year 1982</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>Year 1983</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>Year 1984</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>Year 1985</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>Year 1986</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work unless I give a height to my flex-container, which I don't like as the years should just be split evenly.

Comment: Flexbox is no good for what you want then, go look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 0):

Remove flex-direction from the CSS and use `text-align: center` then you will be good to go.